# Combinatory with n picked elements and limited repetitions in Python

Tags: python

actually I'm looking for combinatory with a limited number of repetitions, I know in python in itertools we already have for no repetitions and with ANY repetition, but I can't found anything for this.

Lets remember, a Combinatory we pick n elements, with a max repetitions, and in the elements, we don't care the order, (A, B, C) is the same as (B, C, A).

Here an example:

A B, C
picking 2, repeated 0:

A, B

A, C

B, C

picking 2, repeated 1:

A, A

A, B

A, C

B, B

B, C

C, C

The functions combinations and combinations_with_replacement doesn't give this behavior, is like what I'm looking for is the mix of both.

Lets be clear, the number of repetitions is the max, so with ABCD, pick 3 and repeat 2, AAB would be valid.

Is there a lib or module with somthing like this?

**Considerations:**

I use big list to apply this, so even If I can filter the results from combinations_with_replacement is not very efficient one by one, I need a generator to not overload the ram.

I would like to avoid this method, or some other more efficient:

```
def Combs2(data, pick, rep):
    for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(data, pick):
        s = set(i)
        show = True
        for j in s:
            if i.count(j) > (rep+1):
                show = False
                break
        if show:
            yield i
```

I test this code, is soo slow that kills every multiprocessing that I'm using, instead using the cores ends using 1....

**Edited:**

To show the difference with combinations_with_replacement

We have ABCDE, lets pick 3 elements with 1 rep.

here example, AAB, BBC, BCA

AAA would be not valid.

We can't get this with combinations_with_replacement or combinations.

Comment: You need to tell us what you WANT.  The lists you're showing are exactly what `combinations_with_replacement` produces.

Comment: Hi no, that function don't give that..., doesn't support for example with 4 elements with a max repetition of 2 elements.

Comment: OK, so the key problem is that you're getting too many results.  You don't want "AAA" to be produced from `combos('ABCD',3,2)`.  You could filter the `combinations_with_replacement` results; it's output is pretty darned close to what you want.

Comment: Yes, I know it can be done, is not so hard, but if there is already a lib with an implementatoin would be great, and better if is contructed efficiently, the second problem there is I would need to filter one by one, I use big combinations, and that can slow the code.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations and https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Hi, combinations doesn't support repeated elements.

Comment: In effect, you are trying to find multisets of a given cardinality which also have an upper bound on the multiplicity of the elements. Perhaps a modification of [stars and bars encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a one-to-one correspondence between the combinations that you seek and k-tuples of bounded non-negative integers with a given target sum. For example,

`AAB`, when drawn from `ABC` consists of `2 A, 1 B and 0 C`, so the correspondence is `AAB <=> (2,1,0)`.

One strategy is to write a generator for such tuples and then decode it as it generates to get the output that you want:

```
#generates multisets of a given size but with bounded multiplicity

#The following generator generates all tuples of
#non-negative integers of length k
#bounded by d and summing to n
#shouldn't be called if n > k*d

def f(n,k,d,path = ()):
    if n == 0:
        yield path + (0,)*k
    elif k == 1:
        yield path + (n,)
    else:
        lower = max(0,n - (k-1)*d)
        upper = min(n,d)
        for i in range(lower,upper+1):
            yield from f(n-i,k-1,d,path + (i,))

def bounded_combos(items,count,bound):
    for t in f(count,len(items),bound):
        combo = []
        for item,count in zip(items,t):
            combo.extend([item]*count)
        yield combo
```

For example,

```
>>> for c in bounded_combos('ABC',3,2): print(c)

['B', 'C', 'C']
['B', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'C', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'B']
```

In terms of the number tuples:

```
>>> for t in f(3,3,2): print(t)

(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 1, 0)
```

As far as how many goes, you can work out a recursive formula for the number of combinations with the key idea that if

```
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_k = n
```

then

a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_k = n - a_1

hence the count for a given k and n can be reduced to counts for k-1 and smaller n. A naive implementation of this recursion would involve repeatedly evalauting the same expression, but [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) makes it feasible for large k,n:

```
def g(n,k,d):
    memo = {} #memoization dictionary
    def h(n,k):
        if (n,k) in memo:
            return memo[(n,k)]
        else:
            if n == 0:
                count = 1
            elif k == 1:
                count = 1
            else:
                lower = max(0,n - (k-1)*d)
                upper = min(n,d)
                count = sum(h(n-i,k-1) for i in range(lower,upper+1))
            memo[(n,k)] = count
            return count
    return h(n,k)
```

Examples:

```
>>> g(3,3,2)
7
>>> g(10,5,5)
651
>>> g(100,20,10)
18832730699014127291
```

I don't know of any closed-form formula for these. As an experiment, I evaluated

```
','.join(str(g(n,n,2)) for n in range(1,11))
```

and pasted it into the search bar of the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) and got a very interesting hit: [A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426), the central trinomial coefficients, which are discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle). If you rerun this experiment with different choices of `n,k,d`, you might stumble upon a nice formula for the overall function.

Comment: Hi, I don't get very well the code but the concept yes, the code seems to not be working fine, tested list(combs2([1, 2, 3], 2, 1)) and list(combs2([1, 2, 3], 2, 2)) is not getting the right results, and the result it self is not a combinatory, the combinatory have elements where the we don't care the order, ('B', 'C', 'A') and ('A', 'B', 'C') are the same elements. I tested a code like this before, and there 2 things, 1) as a generator we can't check a new element with the past elements, 2) doing that we will can't use big list because of the ram. (we would need store all the past data)

Comment: @Latot I came up with a radically different approach. It is a trickier problem than I realized at first. I was able to reduce it into a problem in [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) and came up with a recursive approach which seems to work.

Comment: :O Nice!, this is pretty well designed, this should be added to itertools, I tested the efficiency comparing your last concept with this, I already had a working code from the past concept, and this is a lot more efficient, my only question if you know it, how many combinations this generate?, I tested the code and seems to work fine :D

Comment: @Latot It is much too specialized for itertools. I added a count function. If this answer helps, you could consider marking it as accepted.